# Задача на собеседовании младшего-Java разработчика

Tags: java, задание-на-собеседовании

Недавно побывал на собеседовании задали вот такое задание. На ее выполнение мне дали минут 40, поэтому возможно не все так просто как кажется:

Задача 1.
Реализовать парковку размера n //id номер паркоместа

```
boolean park(String id); // смогли запарковать?

void unpark(String id);
```

Необходима помощь в решении этой задачи

Вот мое решение.
Будем считать, что массив парковочных мест поступает к нам извне в аргументе конструктора

```
package parking;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Parking {
    int size;
    ArrayList<String> parkingArr;

    public Parking(int size, ArrayList parkingArr) {
        this.size = size;
        this.parkingArr = parkingArr;
    }

    public boolean park(String id) {
        return !parkingArr.contains(id);
    }

    public void unpark(String id) {
        if (parkingArr.get(parkingArr.indexOf(id)) != null)
            parkingArr.set(parkingArr.indexOf(id), null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Почему String-то?

Comment: *Необходима помощь в решении этой задачи* Ну так показывайте своё решение и рассказывайте, что не так... поможем.

Comment: Текст задачи точь-в-точь как задали:)

Comment: Вопрос неконкретный. Что значит "помощь"? Вы же её как-то решили? "Правильность" решения в голове у спрашивающего, мы туда точно не залезем. Возможно, вам лучше показать своё решение и спросить что вам кажется неправильно сделанным, что именно непонятно осталось и немного залезем в область "что можно было сделать иначе и главное - зачем" (тут мы вторгаемся в область субъективного и оно может у конкретного интервьюера различаться).

Comment: @andreymal А почему id не может быть стрингом?

Comment: @Capt.Somov Вставьте код в текст вопроса, а не в комментарий.

Comment: @Эникейщик думаю Long/long было бы правильней.

Comment: @Санаев Почему это? Берем в качестве id госномер транспортного средства и всё.

Comment: @Эникейщик написано же номер паркоместа, я все - таки предполагаю это целочисленное значение\

Comment: @Эникейщик может, но зачем?

Comment: @Санаев Хех, тогда да. Но с этой точки зрения странные методы у паркоместа - park() и  unpark(). Можно, конечно, предположить, что это методы автомобиля, а не паркоместа, но зачем тогда автомобилю  в методе выпарковки нужен номер паркоместа...

Comment: @Санаев на парковках можно встретить идентификаторы мест в формате `<буква ряда><номер места>`. Типа "D11".

Comment: @andreymal А какая разница? И даже у паркоместа в реальной жизни id очень часто стринг, а не номер. А12, В07, С22...

Comment: Ну автор правда не знаю чем тебе помочь, задача элементарная, погугли посмотри как улучшить свой код

Answer (score 0, accepted):

допустим:

```
public class Parking {
    // коллекция машиномест
    Set<String> parkingPlaces = new HashSet<>();
    // емкость паркинга
    final int PARKING_SIZE;

    // конструктор c параметром емкость
    public Parking(int PARKING_SIZE) {
        this.PARKING_SIZE = PARKING_SIZE;
    }

    // поставить машину
    // нельзя поставить машину на занятое место или если количество мест превышает размер парковки
    public boolean park(String id) {
        if (parkingPlaces.size() >= PARKING_SIZE || parkingPlaces.contains(id)) return false;
        parkingPlaces.add(id);
        return true;
    }

    // забрать машину можно всегда
    public void unpark(String id) {
        parkingPlaces.remove(id);
    }
}
```

все требования выполнены?

конечно странно что машиноместо можно назвать Маша или Таня, и причем каждый раз по разному, но это дело вкуса

Comment: Спасибо @Mark, скажите еще почему вы выбрали HeshSet,  а не LinkedList например?

Comment: Можно выбрать почти любую коллекцию, но судя по заданию и смыслу  тут нет необходимости использовать функционал листа, а необходимо просто множество уникальных объектов, т.е. Set и его простейшая реализация HashSet.